# Accessing all month and weekday names on instance level in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there an elegant way to access the names of the months and weekdays in moment.js without changing the global moment.js object.

What I have currently in place is

```
var localeData = moment.localeData(superDynamicallyLoadLocale());
var months = localeData._months;
```

This seems to be rather fragile, as the name for the actual months array can change at the maintainers discretion.

I've had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303343/660848) which is *acceptable*, but is there a way that does not involve iteration over the months/weekdays? After all, the data is there in the correct format already.

Comment: I have the same question: moment.weekdays() returns a list of weekdays, but moment.localeData(locale).weekdays() requires you to pass a moment object and will return the weekday of that object. Can I just get a list of the weekdays based on the specified locale?