# Get month name of last month using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I use the following code to get startDate and endDate of the last months.

```
// Previous month
var startDateMonthMinusOne = moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month").unix();
var endDateMonthMinusOne   = moment().subtract(1, "month").endOf("month").unix();

// Previous month - 1

var startDateMonthMinusOne = moment().subtract(2, "month").startOf("month").unix();
var endDateMonthMinusOne   = moment().subtract(2, "month").endOf("month").unix();
```

How can i do to get also the month name ? (January, February, ...)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303164/get-all-months-name-from-year-in-moment-js

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Instead of `unix()` use the `format()` function to format the datetime using the `MMMM` format specifier for the month name.

```
var monthMinusOneName =  moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month").format('MMMM');
```

See the chapter [Display /  Format in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 63):

You can simply use [`format('MMMM')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Here a working example:

```js
var currMonthName  = moment().format('MMMM');
var prevMonthName  = moment().subtract(1, "month").format('MMMM');

console.log(currMonthName);
console.log(prevMonthName);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```