# How to show current and previous month in js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to show current month and all previous months using moment.js in javascript, How to write code using moment.js?

Comment: Have a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303336/7124761

Comment: Have a look at my ans to use the months initialized by `moment.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go. :)

```
var i = parseInt(moment().format('MM')) - 1;
while(i >= 0) {
 console.log(moment().subtract(i--, 'months').format('MMMM'));
}
```

Comment: Do we have any options to get months without define "allMonths" array?

Comment: This gets only current and previous month. Need all previous months as requested by OP.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with plain `javascript` too, no need of any extra library (`moment`)

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var todaysDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = months[todaysDate.getMonth()];
console.log('Current month ' + currentMonth);
console.log('Previous month(s) ');
for(let i = months.indexOf(currentMonth) - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(months[i]);
}
```

Comment: This code showing me only current month , not previous monthsThis is the Result: 
 "Current month Jul"
"Previous month(s) "

Comment: @Rupali edited added `months.indexOf(currentMonth)` instead of `currentMonth - 1` in for loop initialization, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From `moment.js`, `moment.months()` and `moment.monthsShort()` can be used.

```js
var currentmonth = new Date().getMonth();
console.log(moment.months().slice(0,currentmonth+1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get this by using moment.js library

```js
document.write(moment().month());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

You'll get the answer 6 instead of 7 as this is July but this is not wrong as it's written in momentjs documentation that the months are zero indexed so if you want to print 7 you should write it as

```js
document.write(moment().month()+1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

For more answers you should follow this link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/