# NavDropdown Tab not set to active when Dropdown Item link is active (react-bootstrap)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

I'm still quite new to Typescript and react and unfortunately don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I have a tab style nav with a NavDropdown.
Unfortunately the dropdown is the only tab that does not get the active class when one of the dropdown items is selected.
I have already seen that some people had this problem and could solve it somehow but I can't find a way to do it in my case.
Can anyone help me?

Currently my nav looks like this:

```
  <Nav variant="tabs">
    <Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Link
        onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => setTab(e, "today")}
        href="#today"
      >
        today
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>

    <NavDropdown
      title={activeTab === "month" ? dateFormat(dateStart!, "MMMM yyyy") : "month"}
      id="month"
    >

      {months.map((m) => (
        <NavDropdown.Item onClick={() => setMonth(m)} key={dateFormat(m, "MMMM yyyy")}>
          {dateFormat(m, "MMMM yyyy")}
        </NavDropdown.Item>
      ))}
    </NavDropdown>
```

Comment: To have the selection on click add `eventKey` to `NavDropdown.Item`. But to make it selectable with state change it also required the `active` prop (e.g. changing to current Month). Please have a look at the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-navbar-demo-yq2sk).

Comment: @AWolf Thanks a lot for the codesandbox, it helped me already a bit :-)
The problem is that the tab for the month is not shown as active when selecting a month, even in your example... :(
That's what I'm trying to do, or how it should look:
https://prnt.sc/14dlm4n
Unfortunately I just can't get it to work in react-bootstrap....
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You can add that with the `title` on the `NavDropDown`. I've changed it in the Codesandbox. If there is no other format needed, you could also use directly `{month}` for the title.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm bad at describing my problem exactly. I was able to set the title to the current month. 
My problem is that the tab with the current month is not displayed as an active tab when a month is selected.
So this is what it currently looks like when a month is selected: https://prnt.sc/14dq5ce
But this is what it should look like when a month is selected: https://prnt.sc/14dlm4n

Or do you already know what I mean and I just didn't understand your answer? :/

Comment: OK, no problem. Now, I've got the problem. Set `active` prop on `NavDropdown` with the `activeTab` state variable. I've updated the code in the sandbox. So the tab of `month` is activated once a month is selected.

Comment: Yess, that solved my problem!
Thank you very much for your help <3 @AWolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the following parts to fix the tab navigation and month selection:

- Added `defaultActiveKey={activeTab}` to the `Nav` component to activate the tab on load
- `Nav.Link` added `eventKey="today"` to have the key for the today tab set up properly
- On `NavDropdown.Item` added `active={m === month}` where `m` is the iterator of the map (e.g. Jan 2021, Feb 2021 etc) and month is the selected month. This is needed so the selection in the drop-down is working.
- In the `onClick` of the drop-down items added `setMonth` & `setTab` to update the state.
- On `NavDropdown` added `active={activeTab === "month"}` so the tab navigation is correctly updating.

I've also used [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to generate the month array and to format the months. Generation of the array is from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303336/1483981).

You can have a look at the code below or in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-navbar-demo-yq2sk).

```js
/*import moment from "moment";
import { useState } from "react";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";*/

const {useState} = React;
const {Nav, NavDropdown} = ReactBootstrap;
const MONTH_FORMAT_STR = "MMM yyyy";
const months = Array.apply(0, Array(12)).map(function (_, i) {
  return moment().month(i).format(MONTH_FORMAT_STR);
});

const curMonth = moment().format(MONTH_FORMAT_STR);

function App() {
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(curMonth);
  const [activeTab, setTab] = useState(`month`);
  const [dateStart, setStart] = useState(""); // not implemented yet

  return (
    <Nav variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey={activeTab}>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link
          eventKey="today"
          onClick={() => {
            setTab("today");
            console.log("set month", curMonth);
            setMonth(curMonth);
          }}
          href="#today"
        >
          today
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <NavDropdown
          id="month"
          active={activeTab === "month"}
          title={moment().month(month).format("MMMM YYYY")}
        >
          {months.map((m) => (
            <NavDropdown.Item
              title={m}
              eventKey={m}
              active={m === month}
              onClick={() => {
                setMonth(m);
                setTab("month");
              }}
              key={m}
            >
              {m}
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          ))}
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav.Item>
      {activeTab} {month}
    </Nav>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/1.5.2/react-bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-Mw0NWa5M4d73pjqO5CY7Olq0yjPg80GsKCRHpy114idMaX8v+scJmRvhWbXTct8inkKGJNzBvMyWG4ok79zigQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

  
<div id="root"/>
```